# Can I get the bounding boxes of individual characters with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I came across a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.04224.pdf) which uses synthetic handwriting data generated with the ImageMagick convert command, using a lot of different handwriting fonts ([Example images from paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEvtK.png)).

They have annotated these images with their transcriptions, but I would like to annotate them with a bounding box for each individual character. I was wondering if this is possible with ImageMagick or any other available tool/script/code.

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for this forum. Please read the help section of this forum for how to ask a good question and what are appropriate questions. ImageMagick can extract each character using connected components processing. Likewise you can do that or contours or blobs from OpenCV. The issue is that dots on "i"s will also be separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using ImageMagick to iteratively generate new characters one at a time and by masking out the previous characters with OpenCV to get the bounding box for the new character ([Example result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHD2q.png)).

Example code:

```py
import subprocess
import numpy as np
import cv2

full_text = 'OpenCV'
fname = 'test.jpg'
im_size = 'x75'
font = '"ambarella/Ambarella.ttf"'
other_options = '-gravity West -stroke black'

bboxes = []
prev_img = None

# For each letter
for i in range(len(full_text)):
    text = '"' + full_text[:i + 1] + '"'
    fname = 'test_out/' + str(i) + '.jpg'
    command = 'convert -size ' + im_size + ' -font ' + font + ' ' + other_options + ' label:' + text + ' ' + fname
    subprocess.run([command], shell=True)
    img = cv2.imread(fname, 0)
    # Threshold the image
    ret, img = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    if prev_img is None:
        inv = 255 - img
        nonzero = cv2.findNonZero(inv)
        x1, y1, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(nonzero)
        x2 = x1 + w
        y2 = y1 + h
        prev_img = img.copy()
        bboxes.append((x1, y1, x2, y2))
    else:

        h, w = img.shape
        d_h, d_w = h - prev_img.shape[0], w - prev_img.shape[1]
        # Pad the older image
        if d_w > 0:
            prev_img = cv2.copyMakeBorder(prev_img, d_h, 0, 0, d_w, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=255)

        # Mask the previous letters
        nonzero_prev = (prev_img == 0)
        masked_out = img.copy()
        masked_out[nonzero_prev] = 255

        # Get bounding box of new letter
        inv = 255 - masked_out
        nonzero = cv2.findNonZero(inv)
        x1, y1, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(nonzero)
        x2 = x1 + w
        y2 = y1 + h
        bboxes.append((x1, y1, x2, y2))
        # Set prev image to current image
        prev_img = img.copy()

# Visualize results
colors = ((255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255))
img = cv2.imread(fname)
for i, b in enumerate(bboxes):
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = b
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), colors[i % len(colors)], 1)

cv2.imwrite('boxes.png', img)
```

Comment: I do not understand why you would need OpenCV just to draw rectangles. Can that not be done in ImageMagick? In fact you can just add a 1 pixel border to each character image and composite that.

Comment: I did it in OpenCV because I'm not that familiar with ImageMagick, I only use ImageMagick to draw the characters.